# AJAX Post Function without form Not Reset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hello i'm kinda confused with ajax POST method, i try to make api request and since the respond have a similar parameter i make it as one global function so it can be use by my other html / js in other page, i know that the ajax post will make the function required to refreshed. but i don't know how to use my ajax function on html form and since that i directly using button to call the request function but it will end up blocked the next request call (GET/PUT/DELETE become not executable), since i'm not using the html form can i refresh the function without refreshing the whole page or i will need to use html form insteed? any explain or response will be grateful

here my example code of js

```
document.getElementById('confirmSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var query = {};
    query['a'] = 'a';
    query['b'] = 'b';
    query['c'] = 'c';
    request(url, query, 'POST');
});

function request(url, query, method){
if (method == 'POST'){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
    });
}
else{
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
    });
}

document.getElementById("div-overlay-w-100-h-100").style.display = 'block';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    dataType: "text json",
    type: method,
    data: query,
    timeout: 900000,
    success: function(response){
      // LONG PROCESS HERE
    },
    error:function(rr){
      console.log(rr);
    }
});
}
```

here is my html

```
<div class="pcp-tabs-a-container" style="margin-left: 10%;">
    <div class="pcp-add-container-a-container" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <label for="id" class="form-label" style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>ID*:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" style="max-width: 88%; cursor: text;" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="pcp-add-container-a-container" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <label for="nama" class="form-label" style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>Name*:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="nama" id="nama" class="form-control" style="max-width: 88%; cursor: text;" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="pcp-add-container-a-container" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <label for="desc" class="form-label" style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>Desc*:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control" style="max-width: 88%; cursor: text;" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="pcp-add-container-a-container" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <label for="info" class="form-label" style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>Info:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="info" id="info" class="form-control" style="max-width: 88%; cursor: text;" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="pcp-add-container-a-container" style="margin-top: -10px;">
        <label for="order" class="form-label" style="font-size: 16px;"><strong>Order:</strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="order" id="order" class="form-control" style="max-width: 88%; cursor: text;" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="btn-primary" id="confirmSubmit" style="margin-bottom: 20px; height: 40px; width: 130px; margin-left: 10px; font-size: 16px; border-radius: 5px;">Submit</button>
</div>
```

EDIT:
thanks to @Ravi Makwana awesome answer make me got the exactly problem i'm looking for, i edit some line to make it more perfect since my if else method function will keep the ajax not override. so rather than setup the ajaxsetup directly i added it inside the array as suggested by @Ravi Makwana

```
var ajaxSetup = {
    url: url,
    method: method,
    dataType: "text json",
    type: method,
    data: query,
    timeout: 900000,
    success: function(response){
      // LONG PROCESS HERE
    },
    error:function(rr){
      console.log(rr);
    }
};
if (method == 'POST'){
    ajaxSetup.headers= {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    };
    ajaxSetup.processData= false;
    ajaxSetup.contentType= false;
    ajaxSetup.cache= false;
}
else {
    ajaxSetup.headers= {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    };
}
```

change above code to

```
var ajaxSetup = {
    url: url,
    method: method,
    dataType: "text json",
    type: method,
    data: query,
    timeout: 900000,
    success: function(response){
      // LONG PROCESS HERE
    },
    error:function(rr){
      console.log(rr);
    }
};
if (method == 'POST'){
    ajaxSetup['processData'] = false;
    ajaxSetup['contentType'] = false;
    ajaxSetup['cache'] = false;
}
```

Comment: dataType should be either text or json not both

Comment: @LelioFaieta i didn't know if dataType could only take one parameter, but thanks for your sugestion, it's give me more knowladge with ajax parameter

Comment: it could if  you are receiving text and trying to have jquery convert it to json. Otherwise it is only one and is what you are receivng from the endpoint

Comment: yes since my response from the api is json, i removed the text and use the json dataType insteed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Maybe this work

It's possible that you `$.ajaxSetup` is not overriding your setup

so just try to create variable and set all settings into variable

```
function request(url, query, method){
    var ajaxSetup = {
        url: url,
        method: method,
        dataType: "text json",
        type: method,
        data: query,
        timeout: 900000,
        success: function(response){
          // LONG PROCESS HERE
        },
        error:function(rr){
          console.log(rr);
        }
    };
    if (method == 'POST'){
        ajaxSetup.headers= {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        };
        ajaxSetup.processData= false;
        ajaxSetup.contentType= false;
        ajaxSetup.cache= false;
    }
    else {
        ajaxSetup.headers= {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        };
    }
    
    document.getElementById("div-overlay-w-100-h-100").style.display = 'block';
    $.ajax(ajaxSetup);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for this awesome answer it really solve my problem, now my code can do POST/PUT/DELETE/GET function dynamicly from one global function, i eddit your answer a little since the if else with method parameter will still give the function block because the ajaxSetup will not overiding

Comment: Great good to know.